# Problema com script em Python

Tags: python, script

Gente, estou com um leve problema em um script que criei em Python.

```
print("Agora eu vou dizer algo para você.")
idade = int(input("Me diga sua idade."))
if idade < 18
print("Me desculpe, você não pode dirigir.")
else
print("Que bom, você pode dirigir!")
wait = input("Aperte qualquer tecla para sair do CMD.")
exit
```

O problema é: quando eu executo ele, ele simplesmente abre e rapidamente fecha sozinho, sem eu nem mesmo poder fazer nada nele.

Estou começando a aprender Python e programação agora, então é provável que eu tenha feito algum erro estúpido, como algo de sintaxe, mas não consigo notar qual é.

Bem, eu só criei o script pra testar algumas coisas com o Python, e pelo que você já deve ter notado, ele é algo simples.

O usuário coloca sua idade e o script diz se a pessoa pode dirigir legalmente ou não. Eu só quero resolver o script, na verdade, mais pra saber qual foi meu erro e pra não cometê-lo futuramente, porquê o script em si é totalmente inútil.
Então, qual seria o problema no script que faz com que ele feche sozinho?

Answer (score 2):

Basicamente faltam os ":" no fim da linha do `if` e do `else`

```
print("Agora eu vou dizer algo para você.")
idade = int(input("Me diga sua idade."))

if idade < 18:
   print("Me desculpe, você não pode dirigir.")
else:
   print("Que bom, você pode dirigir!")

wait = input("Aperte qualquer tecla para sair do CMD.")
exit
```

Também faltava a indentação (recuo) nas linhas do `print`, mas isso pode ter sido problema de quando você postou a pergunta, imagino que no seu código original existam os recuos (se não, adicione).

Veja o código funcionando perfeitamente no **[IDEONE](https://ideone.com/pFrKa2)**.
<sub>(com entrada simulada de `19` para o primeiro `input`, e `x` para o segundo)</sub>